# Qt Creator doesn't stop on a breakpoint in the templated code with multiple instantiations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, qt-creator, breakpoints, template-instantiation

I've faced a problem in Qt Creator that looks like a bug, but prior to submitting a ticket I wish to collect more info: is that reproducible, known (maybe there are fixes already), etc.

I'm using Qt Creator 4.11.0 based on Qt 5.14.0 (MSVC 2017). If I add a breakpoint into a template code that has multiple instantiations, by default this breakpoint never fires. Let's create a simple application (e.g. console app), define a tempate function and add a breakpoint inside it:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T func(T val)
{
    return val * 2; // Put a breakpoint here
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication(argc, argv);
    func(1);
    return a.exec();
}
```

The implementation of the function is irrelevant, what is important is that we have just a single instantiation `func<int>`. Everything works as expected, but if we add one more instantiation, something changes:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T func(T val)
{
    return val * 2; // Put a breakpoint here
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication(argc, argv);
    func(1);
    func(1L);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Now we have `func<int>` and `func<long>`, and that is reflected in the *Breakpoints View* (Qt Creator now expands the breakpoint into 2 children, each one identifies the instantiated function). Now neither breakpoint instance is fired!

Interestingly, but if we add one more breakpoint somewhere before the call to `func<T>` (in the non-templated code), the debugger would stop on all 3 breakpoints. Looks like it needs some initialization that is performed on the first stop.

This is very annoying as I have to add a breakpoint to `main` every time I plan to trace my code. I never experienced this issue in outdated Qt Creator 3.5.1. Is that a bug, can that be reproduced in reasonably modern versions? Are there any settings that may trigger this behaviour?

Comment: Also facing this, very annoying...

Comment: @AlGrenadine, I've contacted the Qt team, and looks like the issue is fixed in later versions. I haven't verified however...

Comment: Thanks :) i use 5.14.2 and it's still there. Also use latest QtCreator